# How to get a border for a view with a title given within the border in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a view for which i want set a border for the whole view. Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: Import Quartzcore Framework... YOURVIEW.layer.borderWidth = BORDER_VALUE_IN_FLOAT;

Comment: Not sure why the down votes but either mine or Dhaval is right

Comment: i updated the code check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

In Xib take a UIView and label connect them with their IBOutlets and place label on UiView where you want to show label.
and add QuartzCore framework in project.

```
    In your .h file

@Property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UIView *myView; 
@Property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UILabel *myLbl;

    In Your .m file

    myView.layer.borderWidth=3.0f;
    myView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
    myView.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    myView.layer.cornerRadius=0.0f;

    myLbl.text = @"ReEvaluate"; 
    myLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: What is the layer thing over here? coz i am getting error at the layer.

Comment: its saying that layer is undefined. what is that layer?

Comment: Are you sure that you have added QuartzCore framework in the project and took a UIView.

Comment: You have also imported QuartzCore framework in the .m file. if not then import it because this is error comes when supportable framework is not imported. import like that:#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Comment: Now Create a new demo project ,add  QuartzCore framework and import it. then take a UIView and label and follow steps as mention above.it will works fine . i think their is mistake in your current code.

Answer (score 1):

First u need to add QuartzCore.framework for your project

that is projects->target->build Phaese->link binary with libraries->hear add the `QuartzCore.framework`

then in the .m or in .h file where ur view is crating import `<import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

then u are able to access the layer properties then use the any of the answer posted below

for your view there is layer property `borderWidth` you can set it like

```
   view.borderWidth = 2.5f; //any value
```

and there are lot other layer properties associated with the view u can also use them

you edited the question well use below code to achieve your requirement 
lets try this separate project it is the simple way to achieve your goal

do all settings above wat i mentioned and
just copy and past it in `viewDidLoad` method and run

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //i am guessing heare, suppose your view is somthing like this
     UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 40, 100, 100)];
    myView.layer.borderWidth = 2.5f;
    myView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//hear u got the view with black border


   //now you need to add that label at the top left
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x + 5, myView.frame.origin.y, 25, 4)];//place the label in the specified position suppose if u use the
   label.text = @"Label text";
   label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:3.0f];//set the font to your requirement
   label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
   label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

   //remember the order is important
   [self.view addSubview:myView];//first add the view with boreder
   [self.view addSubview:label];//then add the this label on top of border

 }
```

hope this helps u .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one  , You have to add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

```
self.Yourview.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
self.Yourview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
self.Yourview.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
self.Yourview.layer.cornerRadius=30.5; // if you want corner radius then do this otherwise comment it
```

**EDIT:**

AS per your Requirement :

***UITextField*** with below Steps:

**Step (1)**:

Take Xib or storyboard UITextField.

**Step (2):**
it More proper set the property on textfield:

[image]

**Step (3):**
Make sure it disable ,like below:

[image]

may it will help.

Happy coding..:)

Comment: But how to give the title in between the border? My boss told me there is some BOX control used for the border . Is there anything like that?

Comment: no , not any controller like you say BOX controller , but exactly what you want ? what you try or show me code?

Comment: check the pic i have attached. i want it like that

Comment: then it better to put texfield with border ,make sure it uneditable.

Comment: Since i am new to this i have no idea how do you put textfield border. Will i get the same border like how it is in the pic?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47003/discussion-between-dhaval-bhadania-and-user3202087)

Answer (score 0):

In your .h file

```
@Property(nonatomic,strong)UIView *myView;
```

In your .m file

```
   import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

    @@synthesize myView; 


self.myView.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
self.myView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor Black].CGColor;
self.myView.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
self.myView.layer.cornerRadius=20.0f;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the border properties on the CALayer by accessing the layer property of the button.

First, add Quartz

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Set properties:

```
[[myView layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[[myView layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
myView.layer.cornerRadius=20.0f;
```

See:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CALayer

The CALayer in the link above allows you to set other properties like corner radius, maskToBounds etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the layer of view for displaying border around your view.

myView.layer.borderwidth = 1.0;
myView.layer.borderColor = [[Uicolor blackcolor].CGColor];